# Spring Data MongoRepository save causing Duplicate Key error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongo

Here is the Entity:

```
@Document
@Data
public class ApplicationUser {
    private String name;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String organization = null;
    // other fields
}
```

I fetch this user using their email and then change their name. I use the *autowired* instance of ApplicationUserRepository.

```
ApplicationUser applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.findByEmail("abc@gmail.com");
applicationUser.setName("John Doe 2");
```

Then I try to update this entity again in the database:

```
applicationUserRepository.save(applicationUser);
```

I get a duplicate key error on the field email. Why is this happening?
As far as I get from the documentation, the *save* method updates the same document if the ObjectId is the same. Since I haven't changed the objectId then why is it trying to create a new ApplicationUser during saving?

Comment: For me the issue was related to the entity's `@Version` field. When I forgot to set it for an update I received the DuplicateKey exception. After copying it correctly from the old version of the entity, it worked.

Comment: Marvin, thanks for the great answer! I think you should add it also as an answer, because it can be missed in comments. This helped me a lot, and it is VERY not obvious to understand that this is the reason when the error you get is "duplicate key".

Answer (score 5):

I got the solution.
When creating the entity, I have to explicitly declare the Id.

Here is the Entity:

```
@Document
@Data
public class ApplicationUser {
    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;
    private String name;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String organization = null;
    // other fields
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue where I was retrieving by id and then trying to update the retrieved POJO and then save it back with MongoRepository.save() call. It was on MongoDB 4.x with Spring Boot 2.1.0. I added the @Transactional annotation to my service method and everything worked like a charm. The duplicate key exception on id field was resolved.