# Spring data JPA throwing duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data JPA in my application. From design the `save()` of Spring Data makes an `insert` in DB when the element is not present in DB and performs an `update` when the PK of that element is given.

The problem in this case is happening when the PK is present. To my surprise sometimes I get a

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint...

How is this even possible to be thrown since Spring Data should make an update in this case? Anyone else faced the same issue? How did you fixed it?

EDIT:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class Entity {

  @Id
  @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
  private UUID id;
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "surname")
  private String surname;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code to see what may be missing? Maybe this could help: [Mongo save duplicate key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153457/spring-data-mongorepository-save-causing-duplicate-key-error)

Comment: Please update your question to contain relevant code:
The entity definition, the full stack trace formated as code. The code creating and saving the two entities.

To answer the question as it currently stands: you might have another unique key on a non id column.

Comment: Please check my update. I didn't provide code because I thought it's not relevant to the problem since I am having this problem only some times. Generally update works fine, as it should. But sometimes I get the exception above.

Comment: @SBylemans thanks for your answer but didn't help in my case. The entity is ok and update works in the most of the times.

Comment: @NoahMartin But you did not specify the id in your entity, as said in the link I posted.

Comment: @SBylemans sorry it was a bad copy-paste, the entity has it. Just updated again the code snippet

Comment: Hello! Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Don't know if you eventually figured this out, but adding `@Transactional` in my service class fixed this problem for me