# spring data mongodb calling save twice leads to duplicate key exception

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I try to save an entity with spring data mongodb repository. I have an EventListener that cascades saves.

The problem is, that I need to save an entity to get its internal id and perform further state mutations and saving the entity afterwards.

```
 @Test
    void testUpdate() {
        FooDto fooDto = getResource("/json/foo.json", new TypeReference<FooDto>() {
        });
        Foo foo = fooMapper.fromDTO(fooDto);
        foo = fooService.save(foo);
        log.info("Saved foo: " + foo);
        foo.setState(FooState.Bar);
        foo = fooService.save(foo);
        log.info("Updated foo: " + foo);
    }
```

I have an index on a child collection of foo. It will not update children but will try to insert them twice which leads to org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException.

Why does it not save but tries to insert it again?

Related:

[Spring Data MongoRepository save causing Duplicate Key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153457/spring-data-mongorepository-save-causing-duplicate-key-error/53523979#53523979)

---

Edit: versions:

mongodb 4,
spring boot 2.3.3.RELEASE

---

Edit more details:

Repository:

```
public interface FooRepository extends MongoRepository<Foo, String>
```

---

Entity:

```
@Document
public class Foo {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private FooState state;


    @DBRef
    @Cascade
    private Collection<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();

    
 ...

}
```

CascadeMongoEventListener:

```
//from https://mflash.dev/blog/2019/07/08/persisting-documents-with-mongorepository/#unit-tests-for-the-accountrepository
public class CascadeMongoEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Object> {

    private @Autowired
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public @Override void onBeforeConvert(final BeforeConvertEvent<Object> event) {
        final Object source = event.getSource();
        ReflectionUtils
                .doWithFields(source.getClass(), new CascadeSaveCallback(source, mongoOperations));
    }


    private static class CascadeSaveCallback implements ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback {

        private final Object source;
        private final MongoOperations mongoOperations;

        public CascadeSaveCallback(Object source, MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
            this.source = source;
            this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
        }

        public @Override void doWith(final Field field)
                throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);

            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(DBRef.class) && field.isAnnotationPresent(Cascade.class)) {
                final Object fieldValue = field.get(source);

                if (Objects.nonNull(fieldValue)) {
                    final var callback = new IdentifierCallback();
                    final CascadeType cascadeType = field.getAnnotation(Cascade.class).value();

                    if (cascadeType.equals(CascadeType.PERSIST) || cascadeType.equals(CascadeType.ALL)) {
                        if (fieldValue instanceof Collection<?>) {
                            ((Collection<?>) fieldValue).forEach(mongoOperations::save);
                        } else {
                            ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(fieldValue.getClass(), callback);
                            mongoOperations.save(fieldValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static class IdentifierCallback implements ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback {

        private boolean idFound;

        public @Override void doWith(final Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);

            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Id.class)) {
                idFound = true;
            }
        }

        public boolean isIdFound() {
            return idFound;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: expected behaviour

From the docs in org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations#save(T):

> Save the object to the collection for the entity type of the object to
> save. This will perform an insert if the object is not already
> present, that is an 'upsert'.

---

Edit - new insights:

it might be related to the index on the Bar child collection. (DbRef and Cascade lead to mongoOperations::save being called from the EventListener)

I created another similar test with another entity and it worked.

The index on the child "Bar" entity (which is held as collection in parent "Foo" entity):

```
@CompoundIndex(unique = true, name = "fooId_name", def = "{'fooId': 1, 'name': 1}")
```

---

update: I think I found the problem. Since I am using a custom serialization/deserialization in my Converter (Document.parse()) the id field is not mapped properly. This results in id being null and therefore this leads to an insert instead of an update.

I will write an answer if I resolved this properly.

```
public class MongoResultConversion {

    @Component
    @ReadingConverter
    public static class ToResultConverter implements Converter<Document, Bar> {

        private final ObjectMapper mapper;

        @Autowired
        public ToResultConverter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        public MeasureResult convert(Document source) {
            String json = toJson(source);
            try {
                return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Bar>() {
                });
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }


        protected String toJson(Document source) {
            return source.toJson();
        }

    }



    @Component
    @WritingConverter
    public static class ToDocumentConverter implements Converter<Bar, Document> {

        private final ObjectMapper mapper;

        @Autowired
        public ToDocumentConverter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        public Document convert(Bar source) {

            String json = toJson(source);
            return Document.parse(json);

        }

        protected String toJson(Bar source) {
            try {
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(source);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in my last edit the problem was with the custom serialization/deserialization and mongo document conversion. This resulted in id being null and therefore an insert was done instead of an upsert.

The following code is my implementation of my custom converter to map the objectid:

```
public class MongoBarConversion {

    @Component
    @ReadingConverter
    public static class ToBarConverter implements Converter<Document, Bar> {

        private final ObjectMapper mapper;

        @Autowired
        public ToBarConverter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        public Bar convert(Document source) {
            JsonNode json = toJson(source);
            setObjectId(source, json);
            return mapper.convertValue(json, new TypeReference<Bar>() {
            });
        }

        protected void setObjectId(Document source, JsonNode jsonNode) {
            ObjectNode modifiableObject = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
            String objectId = getObjectId(source);
            modifiableObject.put(ID_FIELD, objectId);
        }

        protected String getObjectId(Document source) {
            String objectIdLiteral = null;
            ObjectId objectId = source.getObjectId("_id");
            if (objectId != null) {
                objectIdLiteral = objectId.toString();
            }
            return objectIdLiteral;
        }


        protected JsonNode toJson(Document source) {
            JsonNode node = null;
            try {
                String json = source.toJson();
                node = mapper.readValue(json, JsonNode.class);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return node;
        }

    }


    @Component
    @WritingConverter
    public static class ToDocumentConverter implements Converter<Bar, Document> {

        private final ObjectMapper mapper;

        @Autowired
        public ToDocumentConverter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        public Document convert(Bar source) {
            try {
                JsonNode jsonNode = toJson(source);
                setObjectId(source, jsonNode);
                String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
                return Document.parse(json);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        protected void setObjectId(Bar source, JsonNode jsonNode) throws JsonProcessingException {
            ObjectNode modifiableObject = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
            JsonNode objectIdJson = getObjectId(source);
            modifiableObject.set("_id", objectIdJson);
            modifiableObject.remove(ID_FIELD);
        }

        protected JsonNode getObjectId(Bar source) throws JsonProcessingException {
            ObjectNode _id = null;
            String id = source.getId();
            if (id != null) {
                _id = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
                _id.put("$oid", id);
            }
            return _id;
        }

        protected JsonNode toJson(Bar source) {
            return mapper.convertValue(source, JsonNode.class);
        }
    }


}
```

So to conclude: two subsequent saves should (and will) definitely lead to an upsert if the id is non null. The bug was in my code.

Answer (score 3):

All MongoDB drivers include functionality to generate ids on the client side. If you only save to get the id, research how to use client-side id generation and remove the first save entirely.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to work around this. But do you have any clue why this won't work anyway? Shouldn't this be a normal update case? (upsert done automatically since the entry with the id is already persisted)

Comment: I don't know. You haven't referenced any documentation that describes what is supposed to happen.

Comment: As I found the bug myself I do not accept this as an answer, but I will reward you the bounty since it is the best answer I could get.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are facing this issue as you try to save for the second time without fetching from db. You are changing the object returned by the save, not the object saved into the db. Try retrieving existing foo by using a method like findById and then perform next steps and saving it

Comment: thank you for your answer, but as I stated in my answer the real problem was that the objects id was not populated when it was returned from the save method since I use custom conversion. Therefore this always resulted in an insert.